# Glyphs are displayed as "brackets" ( [] )

Tags: linux, fonts, unicode, fontconfig

So I've installed FontAwesome from the official Debian (jessie) packages (`fonts-font-awesome`) and using a command such as

```
echo -e "\uf26b"
```

will display me a bracket (or like pasting it into firefox a Internet Explorer Icon --> ). Strange enough it doesn't work with urxvt, gnome-terminal and [lemonbar](https://github.com/krypt-n/bar) but it does with firefox.
Any idea why? (`fc-cache -vf` doesn't help either).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the character has no standard meaning: it is in the "private use" area, which means that different applications can (and do) interpret it in different ways.

Further reading:

- [Unicode.org code charts (results)](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/Code2Chart.pl)

  > The character U+F26B is in one of the Private Use Areas (PUA).
  >
  > The interpretations of such characters are not specified in the Unicode Standard and their use may be determined by private agreement among cooperating users.
  >
  > Blank code charts with header information for PUA characters may be found at the following locations:
  >
  > http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf
  >      http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UF0000.pdf
  >      http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U100000.pdf
- [U+F26B PRIVATE USE CODEPOINT](https://codepoints.net/U+F26B?lang=en)